# Prolog predicate to traverse a grid

Tags: prolog

Consider the following predicate: **path(Start, End, Size, Path)**

**Start** is a cell in the grid identified by the list [row, column].
**End** is a cell in the grid identified by the list [row, column].
**Size** is the list giving the maximum row and column values.
**Path** consists of a list of adjacent cells, where adjacent is left/right and up/down. A
path has no loops; i.e. a cell can only occur once in the list.

With the following query: **path([1,1], [4,4], [4,4], Path]**. A valid path would be: [[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,4], [2,3], [3,3], [3,4], [4,4)].

How would you solve this?

Comment: well, it seems pretty easy, from the start position move to the left or right until you reach the destination column; then move up or down until you reach the destination row and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start. First define path.

```
path(X,Y,[X,Y]):- edge(X,Y).
path(X,Y,[X|Xs]):- edge(X,W), path(W,Y,Xs).
```

Then define edge:

```
edge([X,Y], [X1,Y]) :- X1 is X + 1.
edge([X,Y], [X,Y1]) :- Y1 is Y + 1.
```

Now your predicate:

```
grid_path(START, END, LIMIT, SOLUTION) :-
    within_limit(END, LIMIT),
    path(START,END, SOLUTION).
```

I don't want to spoil the fun, so I'll leave it for you. This solution just generates all the possible candidates and it's highly inefficient. You can play around and optimise the search.

Comment: You don't get all the possible paths.

Comment: Very likely as I haven't tested. Where would the problem be?
I'm aware this goes horizontally and this loops forever, but fixing that is quite trivial. All the paths are implicitly in the solution space though.

Comment: @CapelliC I'm quite sure it's perfectly acceptable and extremely useful to give an approximate solution and leave the rest for OP.